# Enable Java in Modern UI Chrome on Windows 8

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8

I'm using the Modren UI Chrome. Everytime I go into a page that has Java, an yellow bar is displayed on the top of the page saying that "Java is required to display some elements on this page" and ask me to view that page in desktop mode

Is there a way to get Java for Modern UI Chrome?

Comment: If it's absent, it's absent...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, no plugins are allowed in the Metro version of Chrome.

From [techdows](http://techdows.com/2012/06/comparison-between-chrome-in-metro-and-on-desktop.html): "Chrome with built-in flash player 11.3 plays all flash content, but Metro style Chrome won’t support other plugins like Silverlight and Java. Chrome follows Metro IE here- Microsoft  integrated  Flash into Metro IE and allows flash for some sites only. By not allowing install of other plugins battery life can be increased and also yields in clean, secure and fast browser experience for users."