# Java 7 on Google Chrome in Windows 8

Tags: google-chrome, java

I have installed Java (including SDK and JRE) on my new Windows 8 Pro 64bit. It works perfectly in IE but Google Chrome doesn't recognize Java at all. Can anyone let me know if Java works under Chrome in Windows 8? I heard it doesn't work in Windows 8? Is this true?

Is it possible to install Java plugin on Windows 8 Chrome?

Comment: I suppose they are pushing forward the plugin-free web: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ie/hh968248.aspx // https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142064?hl=en-GB // http://superuser.com/questions/498693/enable-java-in-modern-ui-chrome-on-windows-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, after my re-search. It does work, but the following restrictions apply (I am answering so it applies for future visitors):

- Java plugin doesn't work in Metro mode, so you need to open Chrome in desktop mode.
- If you are running 64bit version of Windows 8 Pro, then you need to install both 64bit & 32bit version of Java (yes, it is lame but I am not sure why it is so)

If you follow these steps Java works perfectly on Google Chrome under Windows 8 Pro 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have windows 8, but you can try this:

http://nivesh2.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/java-not-working-in-windows-8-solved/

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

> Solution:
>
> Install latest version of JDK
>
> Latest version of JRE
>
> Notice that if you are running 32 bit browser then you must have x86 bit Java installed. So all those using x64 bit OS must install x86
>   bit JRE if they are using 32 bit browser as in my case this was the
>   problem.
>
> Both x64 and x86 JAVA can be installed simultaneously. So better install both! (i have both installed)
>
> Now, Add the path of java compiler to the environment variable as shown below:
>
> Open Advance System Settings > Environment Variables> System Variables.
>
> Click New (if it doesn’t exist else Edit) : CLASSPATH (variable name), %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib; (variable value),
>
> Click New : JAVA_HOME (name), C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0 (value).
>
> Click Edit in Path: in value add: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;
>
> Save and exit.
>
> Note ‘ ; ‘ separates one path with other just like ‘ . ‘ denotes the end of a line.’
>
> Hope this solves your problem. Enjoy java in windows 8.